# Count Swaps and Comparisons insertionSort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

Trying to run a count on both swaps and comparisons, but quite simply put: I don't know where to put it or how much I should modify the code to get the counts.

```
def insertionSort(alist):
    swap = 0
    compare = 0
    for index in range(1, len(alist)):
        currentvalue = alist[index]        
        position = index        
        while position > 0 and alist[position - 1] > currentvalue:
             alist[position] = alist[position - 1]            
             position -= 1
             #I believe I would put compare += 1 here        
        alist[position] = currentvalue
        #And swap += 1 here, but I'm almost positive it wouldn't give me accurate readings.

   return swap, compare
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your problem. I have come up with an solution.

---

### Code

```
def insertionSort(a_list):
swap = 0
compare = 0
for index in range(1, len(a_list)):
    current_value = a_list[index]
    position = index

    compare += 1
    while position > 0 and a_list[position - 1] > current_value:
         a_list[position] = a_list[position - 1]

         if position != index:
             compare += 1

         swap += 1
         position -= 1

    a_list[position] = current_value

return swap, compare
```

---

### Sample IO

I have tested it against some sample input and output. Here are few of them:

```
Input 1: [1, 2, 3]
Output : Swap: 0    Compare: 2

Input 2: [1, 3, 2]
Swap: 1 Compare: 2

Input 3: [3, 2, 1]
Output : Swap: 3    Compare: 3
```

---

Do comment if you find anything wrong with the answer.